# Specify FLOAT column precision in Peewee with MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: python, mariadb, pymysql, peewee

I am trying to specify the float precision for a column definition in Peewee and cannot find how to do this in the [official docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#FloatField) or in the [github issues](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues?q=is%3Aissue+float+is%3Aclosed).

My example model is below:

```py
DB = peewee.MySQLDatabase(
  "example",
  host="localhost",
  port=3306,
  user="root",
  password="whatever"
)

class TestModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DB

    value = peewee.FloatField()
```

The above creates the following table spec in the database:

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM testmodel;
/*
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
*/
```

What I would like is to specify the [`M` and `D` parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) that the `FLOAT` field accepts so that the column is created with the precision parameters I need. I can accomplish this in SQL after the table is created using the below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE testmodel MODIFY COLUMN value FLOAT(20, 6);  -- 20 and 6 are example parameters
```

Which gives this table spec:

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM testmodel;
/*
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value | float(20,6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
*/
```

But I'd like it be done at table creation time within the peewee structure itself, rather than needing to run a separate "alter table" query after the `peewee.Database.create_tables()` method is run. If there is no way to do this in the `peewee.FloatField` itself then I'd also accept any other solution so long as it ensures the `create_tables()` call will create the columns with the specified precision.

Comment: You will need to create a custom field for this. Take a look at how `DecimalField` is implemented in `peewee` and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @booshong already mentions

The simpelst solution is to subclass the default `FloatField` like this :

```
class CustomFloatField(FloatField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_digits = kwargs.pop("max_digits", 7)
        self.decimal_places = kwargs.pop("decimal_places", 4)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_modifiers(self):
        return [self.max_digits, self.decimal_places]
```

and then use it like this

```
my_float_field = CustomFloatField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did exactly what I needed! I'm going to see if it's possible to merge this change into the library itself too